# Автоперенос некоторых элементов bootstrap\flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, bootstrap4

На большом экране в футере у меня следующее, мне нужно при уменьшении экрана, например, меньше md, чтобы почта и телефон съехали на строку вниз, а лого и соц сети остались на этой же:

[image: больше md]

Должно получить на экранах меньше md

[image: md и меньше]

Вот код:

```
         return (
  <div className="container-fluid bac">
    <div
      className="d-flex justify-content-start flex-wrap row"
      style={{
        paddingTop: "64px",
        overflow: "auto",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap"
      }}
    >
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center pr-5 ml-3">
        <img src={logo} alt="logo" />
      </div>

      <div
        className="d-flex align-items-center py-3"
        style={{ paddingRight: "20px" }}
      >
        <img src={envelope} alt="envelope" />
        <span>info@corridor.com </span>
      </div>
      <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
        <img src={phone} alt="phone" />
        <span>+7 499 586-10-25 </span>
      </div>
      <span className="pr-0 ml-auto">
        <span className="telegram">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="20"
            height="18"
            viewBox="2 0 18 20"
          >
            <path d="M.353 8.35l4.609 1.72 1.783 5.736a.542.542 0 0 0 .862.26l2.569-2.095c.27-.219.653-.23.934-.026l4.633 3.364c.32.232.771.057.851-.328L19.988.655a.543.543 0 0 0-.727-.618L.348 7.333A.544.544 0 0 0 .353 8.35zm6.105.804l9.006-5.547c.162-.1.329.12.19.248l-7.433 6.91a1.54 1.54 0 0 0-.478.922l-.253 1.876c-.033.25-.385.275-.454.033l-.974-3.422a.907.907 0 0 1 .396-1.02z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span className="twitter">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="20"
            height="18"
            viewBox="0 0 18 20"
          >
            <path d="M20 1.922a8.193 8.193 0 0 1-2.356.646A4.12 4.12 0 0 0 19.448.3a8.271 8.271 0 0 1-2.607.996 4.103 4.103 0 0 0-6.991 3.74A11.648 11.648 0 0 1 1.392.75 4.072 4.072 0 0 0 .84 2.812a4.1 4.1 0 0 0 1.824 3.414 4.103 4.103 0 0 1-1.858-.515v.052a4.107 4.107 0 0 0 3.29 4.023 4.156 4.156 0 0 1-1.08.143c-.266 0-.522-.026-.773-.076a4.105 4.105 0 0 0 3.832 2.85 8.232 8.232 0 0 1-5.095 1.753A8.72 8.72 0 0 1 0 14.4a11.597 11.597 0 0 0 6.289 1.846c7.547 0 11.673-6.252 11.673-11.673l-.014-.531A8.193 8.193 0 0 0 20 1.922z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <span className="facebook">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="20"
            height="18"
            viewBox="-3 0 18 20"
          >
            <path d="M10.406.004L7.812 0C4.9 0 3.016 1.932 3.016 4.922v2.27H.408A.408.408 0 0 0 0 7.598v3.289c0 .225.183.407.408.407h2.608v8.297c0 .226.182.408.407.408h3.403a.408.408 0 0 0 .407-.408v-8.297h3.05a.408.408 0 0 0 .407-.407l.002-3.289a.408.408 0 0 0-.409-.408h-3.05V5.268c0-.925.22-1.394 1.425-1.394l1.747-.001a.408.408 0 0 0 .408-.408V.412a.408.408 0 0 0-.407-.408z" />
          </svg>
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <hr
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        opacity: "0.15",
        marginTop: "40px",
        marginBottom: "30px"
      }}
    />
    <div className="row">
      <Link to="/information/confidencial" className="col-md-auto linkText">
        Политика конфиденциальности
      </Link>
      <Link to="/information/rules" className="col-md-auto linkText">
        Правила использования
      </Link>
      <Link to="/information/security" className="col-md-auto linkText">
        Безопасность
      </Link>
      <Link to="/information/comission" className="col-md-auto linkText">
        Комиссия
      </Link>
      <Link to="/contact" className="col-md-auto linkText">
        Контакты
      </Link>
    </div>
    <div className="row pb-5">
      <div className="col">
        <div>
          ИП «Коридор» использует файлы «cookie», с целью персонализации
          сервисов и повышения удобства пользования веб-сайтом. «Cookie»
          представляют собой небольшие файлы, содержащие информацию о
          предыдущих посещениях веб-сайта. Если вы не хотите использовать
          файлы «cookie», измените настройки браузера.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {this.state.windowWidth ? (
      <div className="col justify-content-start px-0 col-xl-offset-4">
        <div>©2018 ИП «Коридор»</div>
      </div>
    ) : (
      ""
    )}

    <div className="row justify-content-end px-0">
      {this.state.windowWidth ? (
        ""
      ) : (
        <div className="col justify-content-start pr-0 col-xl-offset-4">
          <div>©2018 ИП «Коридор»</div>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="col-auto mb-2 justify-content-end">
        <img src={visa} alt="VISA" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-auto mb-2 justify-content-end">
        <img src={paypal} alt="paypal" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-auto mb-2 justify-content-end">
        <img src={master} alt="paypal" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-auto mb-2 justify-content-end">
        <img src={yandex} alt="yandex-money" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-auto mb-2 justify-content-end">
        <img src={webmoney} alt="webmoney" />
      </div>
      <div className="col-auto justify-content-end">
        <img src={american} alt="american-express" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Непонятно как и что у вас свёрстано.
В бутстрапе для этого есть col-md, col-sm,  и т.д. в разделе grid у них всё хорошо документировано.
Если например колонка col-md и внутри неё нужно еще перенести элементы, то нужно смотреть в сторону flex-wrap: wrap;

Comment: код покажите помогу

Comment: @Demon __ ANT добавил  код

Comment: @АлександрМангир я не понял это Реакт тут используетсья

Comment: @Demon __ ANT ага, но там в className есть col и flex. То что нужно. На сколько я знаю это делается с помощью push pull от бутстрапа, но у меня почему-то не получается

Comment: @АлександрМангир это делаетсья с помощью flex-wrap wrap а по точнее к родительскому элементу даете вот такой класс __d-flex flex-wrap__ чтобы если у него потомки не вмещаютсья в блок то переместились вниз.В вашем коде не смогу показать так как я не разобралсья что там происходит

Comment: @Demon __ ANT Я так и делал. Но в этом случае все перемещается на новую строку, а мне нужно, чтоб переместилось все кроме соц. сетей

Comment: Сделайте нормальный пример, что бы можно было ответить.

Comment: @Demon __ ANT
Вот, нужно чтоб при md и меньше экране лого и соцсети не съехали, а съехали только почта и телефон. Причем, чтоб почта и телефон были друг под другом. Как на скрине в вопросе у меня
https://codepen.io/Sasha9520/pen/zJxVvJ

Comment: @Demon __ ANT   обвел в рамку блок с соцсетями, который должен остаться в однйо строчке с лого